How to add .Net Framework into Cyclone DX BoM?
How should .Net Framework be accounted for in a CycloneDX SBoM?
We have C# applications that are developed in VS2022.  We can use cyclonedx-dotnet to automagically generate an SBoMs that contains all the NuGet dependencies, but not .Net Framework itself.
I understand the application probably shouldn't contain information about Framework because that's a deployment time concern.  The application may be deployed to run on varying versions of Framework.  But the application code does use Framework.
Our code is deployed to hardware that is distributed as part of our product.  We have control of which version of Framework our application runs on.  What I want to do is generate an SBoM that contains the components within our application as well as the .Net Framework version that was deployed.  We need that information to fully understand system vulnerabilities.
How would this normally be handled in a CycloneDX SBoM?  Are there tools to add in the .Net Framework that the application is deployed on?
I haven't been able to find a source of SBoMs for .Net Framework.  Does anyone know if such a thing exists?  And where they can be found??  I thought if I could at least find the BoMs for .Net Framework I could merge them into our BoMs.  Or are there other options?
Thanks for any thoughts on this!!!
[1] https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-dotnet
